# Dynamic JFormattedTextFields in JXDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, swingx, jformattedtextfield

I require a field that accepts 4 types of formats: `integer`, `float`, `string` and `date`. When the user requires a date input the UI will present a date picker.

So to simplify the UI to have a singular textfield I created a `JXDatePicker` with `JFormattedTextfield` as it's editor and dynamically assign the formatted factory of the `JFormattedTextfield` to handle `Integer`, `Float`, `String` and `Date` input. Following is a code snippet of the implementation:

```
  public void setFormat(String format)
  {
    // requires integer format
    if (IntegerAttribute.TYPE_NAME.equals(format)) {
      setBoundFormatFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getInstance())));
    }
    // requires float format
    else if (FloatAttribute.TYPE_NAME.equals(format)) {
      setBoundFormatFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat(FLOAT_FORMAT))));
    }
    else if (DateAttribute.TYPE_NAME.equals(format)
            || DateTimeAttribute.TYPE_NAME.equals(format)
            || TimeAttribute.TYPE_NAME.equals(format)) {
      // requires date format
      setDateFormat(model.getDateFormat());
    }
    else {
      // otherwise set to us string
      setBoundFormatFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory()); 
    }
  }

  public void setDateFormat(String dateFormat)
  {
    setBoundFormatFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new DateFormatter(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat))));
  }

  private void setBoundFormatFactory(DefaultFormatterFactory factory)
  {
    m_formattedTextfield.setFormatterFactory(factory);
  }
```

The implementation works for string and date formats however for integers and floats it seems like the JXDatePicker is trying to cast it into a Date data type and therefore causes a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.editorPropertyChange(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1359)
at org.jdesktop.swingx.plaf.basic.BasicDatePickerUI$Handler.propertyChange(BasicDatePickerUI.java:1336)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:339)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:276)
at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8163)
at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(JFormattedTextField.java:782)
at javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.commitEdit(JFormattedTextField.java:513)
```

Is there a way to stop the date picker from trying to cast the value into a date when the field is a number format? Or is there another work around?

Comment: don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve - a JXDatePicker is designed to handle Dates, nothing less and nothing more :-)

Comment: to claify you want a JFormattedTextField that is able to handle `int`s, `float`s `date`s and `string`s?

Comment: Also how would you know the difference between an integer and a float? other than if you check whether the input has a `.`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp yes and when it's a date, the UI will need to provide a date picker. The type to format is distinguished by past user actions, so when the user enters the values, I should already know what format it should be.

Comment: @kleopatra I was trying to combine normal fields (string, int, float) to be used in conjunction with the date picker to simplify the UI.

Comment: If you know in advance what kind of input you want to receive, why not simply replace the input field instead of trying to make one field which can handle anything ?

Answer (score 1):

- never used `JXDatePicker` (I think support only formatted `Date value` by DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat, have to synchronize both formatters),
- you can use `JSpinner` with `SpinnerDateModel` instead of `JFormattedTextField`
- maybe have look at [JCalendar by Kai Toedter](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/), and to use codesource

Comment: JXDatePicker is used elsewhere in the project so to keep the UI consistent I will have to use it. The spinner will work for handling dates but I am not sure how I can use it for strings..